# AppcompatActivity Error with Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I'm getting this error when building android application with Android studio :

```
24192-24192/com.mkapp.apps.demo1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;)
08-20 10:53:23.605  24192-24192/com.mkapp.apps.demo1 I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate, referenced from method com.mkapp.apps.demo1.TourActivity.onCreate
08-20 10:53:23.605  24192-24192/com.mkapp.apps.demo1 W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8393: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;Landroid/os/PersistableBundle;)V
08-20 10:53:23.605  24192-24192/com.mkapp.apps.demo1 D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
```

my dependencies :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

many thanks for your help

old activities which inherit from AppcompatActivity work fine. but if I create new one ,it get the error .
here is my gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mkapp.apps.demo1"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':photocollage')
    compile project(':gWFacebookSDK')
//    compile project(':listViewAnimation')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.0-core.jar')
    compile files('libs/aws-android-sdk-2.1.0-sns.jar')
    compile files('libs/dexmaker-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.1-custom.jar')
//    compile files('libs/listviewanimations_lib-core_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
}
```

Comment: Update your support repository use the latest version 23

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have this issue because you are trying to use [onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)), but this method is available only from API level 21.

I am able to reproduce the issue with this sample code on Android 4.4:

```
public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, new PersistableBundle());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }
}
```

And the issue is resolved removing every occurrence of `PersistableBundle`:

```
public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Check where you use `PersistableBundle` in your `TourActivity` and remove it or update your answer with the code of your activity.

Answer (score 13):

Update your support library to `23` and your `compileSdkVersion` to `23` in build.gradle.

```
compileSdkVersion 23

...

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Then sync your project with gradle files.

Also, Google Play Services is now `7.8.0`

Comment: at last! if you're new to Android Studio and you've just downloaded the latest version (as of june 17 2016) by default your gradle will be set to use support libraries version 24, that seems to be very buggy at this point in time so even a simple activity built from untouched template will not work until you've changed this. VERY frustrating, but you got to this answer eventually so you're on the right way, don't give up :)

Comment: That's not helping i have latest dependencies still it get that error with device below api 21 results no layout is visible.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your `TourActivity` is using a class available only from API level 21 [PersistableBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PersistableBundle.html). The question here is why is doing that.

Remember you new activity have to inherit from `AppCompatActivity` as well.

Quick question, are you overriding `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)` in the problematic activity? If you are doing it you probably are saving a reference to `PersistableBundle` which is not available in the device/emulator. Try removing it if you are not doing nothing there or comment it to try...

Answer (score 4):

First, update your libraries to the latest versions.
Next, clean and rebuild your project.

Also, if this is a full list of libraries that you include:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

then you actually don't need to include this one

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply 
, **Goto** the *File*-> *Invalidate Caches and Restart.*
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cheesy solution, but it actually worked for me !  I manually created the needed path to the missing library :

```
 C:\Users\spomerleau\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs
```

and added the two missing .jar files from [here](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/android-support/android-support-v4.jar.zip).  Android studio finally found the dependencies that needed to execute Java.

Answer (score 0):

1.Just change your dependencies to present in the build.gradle--

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}
```

2.Then it will show to sync gradle, then sync build.gradle to update the changes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Change your app  `build.gradle` like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
```